# What's the difference between child.remove() and parent.removeChild(child)?

Tags: javascript

The only reference I've been able to find to the javascript `remove()` function is [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_remove.asp) on w3schools, which claims the method is for removing options from selects. However, it clearly works as expected when invoking it on any node when I test it in Chrome and Firefox.

Is this newly supported? I've always had to do something like `child.parentNode.removeChild(child)` in the past. Are there any benefits/drawbacks to using one over the other?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

Comment: Please stop using [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/). Try using [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) or [DevDocs](http://devdocs.io/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

`HTMLElement` object has [`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) method. Only modern browsers support the method. It removes the html element.

What you are referring to is the `HTMLSelectElement` (*which implements the `HTMLElement` interface*) object's [`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/remove) method which removes an `option` by index. The method is supported by the old and new browsers. Without passing an index the `select` element itself is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the spec they appear to do the same thing.

https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-childnode-remove

> The remove() method, when invoked, must run these steps:
>
> If context object’s parent is null, terminate these steps.
>
> Remove the context object from context object’s parent.

The last line seems to suggest its doing this anyway child.parentNode.removeChild(child).

https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-removechild

> The removeChild(child) method must return the result of pre-removing child from the context object.

https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-pre-remove

> To pre-remove a child from a parent, run these steps:
>
> If child’s parent is not parent, throw a NotFoundError exception.
> Remove child from parent.
>
> Return child.

As for if there is an advantage for one over the other, I'm not sure there is one. (There possibly could be but I couldn't find anything) It probably just depends on what is better for readability in your context.